# add database connection property to laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

For example, I want to add the property `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` to the MySQL connection.
I already tried the following in `database.php`, but it is being ignored :

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.1.1.1:3306',
        'database'  => 'db_name',
        'username'  => 'db_username',
        'password'  => 'db_password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'options' => array( 'zeroDateTimeBehavior' => 'convertToNull')
    ),
```

Or is there any other way to ignore Date fields when they are '0000-00-00 00:00:00' instead of NULL ? Because they are still being fetched when using `->whereNotNull('DateField')` which causes problems...

Comment: this might help  http://fideloper.com/laravel-pdo-connection-options

Comment: @user4621032 I already read that, but I couldn't find anything on this `zeroDateTimeBehavior` in particular... or should I use `PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING` ?

Comment: I tried `'options' => array(
    PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING
   )` but it is still fetching date fields with '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: oracle_nulls would not work with mysql

Comment: @user4621032 according to http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php it does...

Comment: probably `PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING` is not working here, because the datefield os not empty but zero...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I temporarily solved it with adding a `->where('Datefield', '<>', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')` statement...</strike>

It is not an answer to my question, but a solution for the resulting problem...

**UPDATE**

EDIT: the class below doesn't seem to help after all... I will update it when I find the solution

To make it more generic, a former colleague has extended the Eloquent model instead, so I can get rid of the `->where('Datefield', '<>', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')` statement for all models...

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($model) {
        static::setNullWhenZeroDateTime($model);
        return true;
    });
}

private static function setNullWhenZeroDateTime($model) {
    foreach ($model->toArray() as $name => $value) {
        if ($value == '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
            $model->{$name} = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```